# Android Studio - Toolbar Items - XML Problems

Tags: android, xml

Here is a piece of xml code in android studio that seems very peculiar. For some strange reason, layout has render promblems with the item which I add.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Client_Andro"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="27dp"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@*android:drawable/ic_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</Toolbar>
```

I can give you what I see in my layout [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdXd0.png)

And the render promblem is:

```
The following classes could not be found

 -item (.....)
```

- What is going on?
- Why the item is left of the toolbar still I have use (`layout_alignParentRight="true"`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Client_Andro"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="27dp"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:showAsAction="always"
//this line in error so not display your icon 
        android:icon="@*android:drawable/ic_search"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</Toolbar>


---------------
right ans. is:--remove * 

  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search"
```